# Django rest framework db query slow

Tags: django, serialization, query-optimization, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

- I have a Django model with 16 DecimalFields.
- I have created a
  ListAPIView to fetch this data.
- With ~5000 instances of this model
  in my db, the GET request to this api view is taking more than 15
  seconds.

Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    f1 = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    f2 = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    f3 = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    f4 = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    f5 = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    f6 = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    f7 = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    f8 = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    f9 = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    f10 = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    f11 = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    f12 = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    f13 = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    f14 = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    f15 = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    f16 = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
```

Serializer:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

I am not doing any filtering of the data. When I run the query in the django shell, it runs in a few ms. I assume serialization is the problem here. However, I am using the default ModelSerializer.

All of these fields are in the same table, so I don't see how there could be an N+1 issue here.

What can I do to further profile this issue? Should I expect my queries to be this slow with this many model instances?

Comment: Do you want to take all 5000 values to the client side? If not paginate and serialize only the required items.

Comment: There is nothing we can do but make blind guesses right now. Give us some eyes, give us the model and serializer.

Comment: @ArunGhosh I do want to take all 5000 values to the client side. As this data is only around 1mb, it seems like there should be a way to get from the db to client side in less than 15 seconds.

Comment: @KevinBrown Really? I thought my description of my model and serializer were straight forward enough, but I have updated the question.

Comment: @rawbeans That's... concerning. Usually non-query issues are because of customized models and serializers that do extra processing with the data. But if your serializers and models are bare (like your examples show), you're going to need to pull out an actual Python profiler.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `ListAPIView` try using a `ModelViewSet` instead.

Create a custom viewset for yourself which inherits only `ListModelMixin`

```
class ListModelViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    pass
```

Now extend this to your viewset and write your `queryset` there

```
def get_queryset(self):
    Model.objects.all()
```

This is not a logic which can speed up things because ultimately all of them inherits the same thing but its worth a try.

If this also doesn't work... another possible reason can be that 5000 objects is a pretty large number. Shell does not return all the objects at once. It performs a query for Model.objects.all() but limits the number of objects to 20 followed by this ....(remaining elements truncated)...., so I guess this lessens the time as compared to the web view when it has to bring all the elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of serializer, you can improve the performance by using `Model.objects.values()` instaed of using serializer, This will return the same data very quickly.

Comment: I changed the queryset from Model.objects.all() to Model.objects.values() and the query is still just as slow.

Answer (score 0):

Install [django-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) and see Query time and CPU time. If query is taking time and is doing some lazy loading check [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) & [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

Comment: Query time is 90ms, CPU time is 26000ms. Also, im not sure how prefetch_related and select_related are useful here because all fields are within the same table